# How do you run Javascript in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

This is my first time doing anything like this and google has not helped me much. I can get Javascript to work as part of the html but not as its own file.

I've set up my static files and they work for my CSS but I cannot run any Javascript from the static folder.

The path is below:

[image]

This is in my "base.html"

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css"> <!-- Works -->
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/darkmode.css"> <!-- Works -->
  <!-- Utilities CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/star_rate.css"> <!-- Works -->

</head>

<!-- Scrips -->
<script src="/static/js/all_pages.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Doesn't Work-->
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Doesn't Work-->
```

This is "all_pages.js"

```js
alert("Test 2");
```

and this is an extension of base called "test.html"

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% load static %} 
<script src="/static/js/all_pages.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- I added this in hopes it'd fix the issue -->

<!-- VVV I added this to see if js was not working at all  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Test 01');
</script>
<!-- ^^^ I added this to see if js was not working at all  -->

{% endblock %}
```

I only get the alert "Test 01"

I would expect to get "Test 01" and "Test 02"

Edit:

Full base.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css"> <!-- Works -->
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/darkmode.css"> <!-- Works -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/w95.css"> -->
  <!-- Utilities CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/star_rate.css"> <!-- Works -->

</head>

<!-- Scrips -->
<script src="/static/js/all_pages.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Doesn't Work -->
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Doesn't Work -->

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Not Velox</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="create/">Create Franchise</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test cant push<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Test 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Username -->
          <span class="navbar-text">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <!-- Need to add link to user Profile -->
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">{{user.username}}</button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
          </span>
          <!-- Log out -->
          <span class="navbar-text">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <form action="/signup/logout/" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
                        <svg class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-left" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                            fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M7.854 11.354a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708L5.207 8l2.647-2.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15 8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h9A.5.5 0 0 0 15 8z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M2.5 14.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 13V3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5-1.5h8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 12 3v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-8A.5.5 0 0 0 2 3v10a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h8a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V13a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-8z" />
                        </svg>
                        logout
                    </button>
                </form>
            </a>
            {% endif %}            
          </span>
          <!-- Sign up -->
          <span class="navbar-text">
            {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup/">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                    <svg class="bi bi-person-plus-fill" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M1 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm7.5-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H13V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" />
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13 7.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2z" />
                    </svg>
                Sign Up
                </button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
          </span>
          <!-- Log in -->
          <span class="navbar-text">
            {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup/login">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                    <svg class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                        fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M8.146 11.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708L10.793 8 8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0z" />
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-9A.5.5 0 0 1 1 8z" />
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M13.5 14.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 15 13V3a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-1.5-1.5h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 4 3v1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v10a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-8A.5.5 0 0 1 5 13v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 1.5h8z" />
                    </svg>
                    Login
                </button>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
          </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <div class="p-3 m-3">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for pyshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
    'franchise.apps.FranchiseConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'debug_toolbar'
   
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

INTERNAL_IPS = ("http://127.0.0.1/")

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pyshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pyshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]  

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Comment: Is your js in the head tag or body tag of your base.html,Maybe you should show us your full base.html and test.html code

Comment: even you say your css files are working, add your settings file as well. The body tag is not correct though

Comment: @Ceetified_karma added that now. The full test.html is already what's there.

The js is not in ether body or head. Moving them to one then the other doesn't seem to fix if that's what it should do

Comment: @Lemayzeur added that now. What's wrong with body tag? (Very new to all of this and using videos to try and teach myself so I'm missing a lot of the obvious basic shit)

Comment: What does your browser say? are you able to load the js content in your browser? remove the `load static` out the block and put it after extends. Make sure your js file does not contain any issue, a js error syntax may block everything

Comment: remove your SECRET_KEY. Never post that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this ur settings

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   )
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your static files correctly in the html. Try

```
<script src="{% static 'js/all_pages.js' %}"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="/static/js/all_pages.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Doesn't Work-->
```

Comment: I may be wrong in this but I think these both do the same thing but written in a different way